# What selector can I use to exclude IDs with a suffix?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of divs on a page (*bg_1, bg_5, bg_112* etc.) that I'd like to assign the style 'display:inline-block'.

However, I have other divs called *bg_1_log, bg_5_log, bg_112_log* etc..) that I do not want to assign this style to.

I have tried:

```
 $('[id^=bg_]').attr('style','display:inline-block');
```

This works, but of course that assigns the style to all divs that start with '*bg_*', including *bg_112_log*...

How can I "assign a style to all divs that are just bg_+number?

I'm using jQuery so either that or JS would be fine.

Comment: can you assign a class to them while generating the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the selector using [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) like:

```
$('[id^=bg_]').not('[id*=_log]')
```

Or, you can also use regex as @zfrisch suggested but here's an improved version (Selector not only limitted to div):

```
$('*').filter(function() { return this.id.match(/bg_\d$/) })
```

Or, even like:

```
$('*').attr('id').match(/bg_\d$/)
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know I could use the .not in conjunction with the contains selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's `.filter` method

```js
$('div')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.id.match(/bg_\d$/);
    })
    .css("backgroundColor", "green");
```

```css
div:after {
  content: "test";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg_1"></div>
<div id="bg_2"></div>
<div id="bg_3"></div>
<div id="bg_4"></div>
<div id="bg_5"></div>
<div id="bg_6"></div>
<div id="bg_1_log"></div>
<div id="bg_2_log"></div>
<div id="bg_3_log"></div>
<div id="bg_4_log"></div>
<div id="bg_5_log"></div>
<div id="bg_6_log"></div>
```

Or as another answer pointed out `.not`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to select the elements whose id ends with `_log` then you can use following code:

```
$('[id^=bg_]').not('[id$=_log]').attr('style','display:inline-block');
```